# While loop only exiting after conditions are met twice in a row

Tags: c#

**EDIT:** Oh My God - that's what copy / paste does for you. I forgot to delete the one outside the loop. SORRY EVERYONE. And thanks **Doorknob 冰**

I'm very new to programming, and I'm trying to use what I know (which isn't much) to create a Tic Tac Toe game. I know I'm likely going about it in one of the most inefficient ways imaginable, but I don't want to fix that for now, I'd just like to get something I've done (almost) entirely on my own to work before I see how I 'should' have done it.

Anyway, I've got to the point where I can print the grid by calling a method, and now I'm trying to find a way of taking the user input to mark a grid position (which I will later turn into a method).

However whenever I run the program and type '1' for example, my while loop goes around again, and I have to type '1' again, but this second time it will do what I was expecting the first time and reprint the updated grid.

Here's my code:

```
namespace TicTacToe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int userChoice = 0;
            bool inputCheck = true;
            string[,] grid = new string[3, 3];

            grid[0, 0] = "[ ]";
            grid[0, 1] = "[ ]";
            grid[0, 2] = "[ ]";
            grid[1, 0] = "[ ]";
            grid[1, 1] = "[ ]";
            grid[1, 2] = "[ ]";
            grid[2, 0] = "[ ]";
            grid[2, 1] = "[ ]";
            grid[2, 2] = "[ ]";

            Console.WriteLine(printGrid(grid));

            Console.Write("Please choose a space with coordinates 1 (top left) to 9 (bottom right): ");
            userChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (inputCheck == true)
            {
                inputCheck = false;

                Console.Write("Please choose a space with coordinates 1 (top left) to 9 (bottom right): ");
                userChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (userChoice == 1)
                    grid[0, 0] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 2)
                    grid[0, 1] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 3)
                    grid[0, 2] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 4)
                    grid[1, 0] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 5)
                    grid[1, 1] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 6)
                    grid[1, 2] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 7)
                    grid[2, 0] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 8)
                    grid[2, 1] = "[X]";
                else if (userChoice == 9)
                    grid[2, 2] = "[X]";
                else
                    inputCheck = true;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(printGrid(grid));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string printGrid(string[,] grid)
        {
            int rowLength = grid.GetLength(0);
            int columnLength = grid.GetLength(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < columnLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", grid[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n"); //double line spacing
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to work out why it works the second time but not the first? I've double checked that I've put the bool I created in the loop correctly.

Perhaps it's something to do with my userChoice assignment in the loop?

**EDIT:** Oh My God - that's what copy / paste does for you. I forgot to delete the one outside the loop. SORRY EVERYONE. And thanks **Doorknob 冰**

Comment: Because you ask for it twice? (Once before the loop, and once within the loop)

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Since like @Doorknob冰 mentioned, you're just asking user input twice. Nothing to do with your while loop.

Comment: Please respect the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Doorknob 冰 noted, you're asking for the input twice. The first time you ask for it you don't actually do anything with it, so that's why it *seems* to do nothing, although that's exactly what you coded it to do.

I suggest you think about what you actually want: the program should receive user input at least once and then verify that it's a valid position. If it is valid, the while loop exits.

This is exactly what a `do{ stuff } while(condition);` loop is for.